# How to return an object with specific fields in Spring Boot MongoDB after Distinct

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.2 and MongoDB 3.4.6.

```
{
    "_id" : "File001.1",
    "serialNumber" : "F001",
    "account" : {
        "accountName" : "ACCT01",
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Trying to fetch Records from a MongoDB Collection say "Account" with the data for ONLY the fields  say , "serialNumber" and "account.accountName"

```
Query query = new BasicQuery("{}", "{serialNumber:1, account.accountName:1}");
List<Account> accounts = mongoTemplate.getCollection("Account")
                    .distinct("serialNumber", query.getQueryObject());
```

The above returns Lists of String[serialNumber's] instead of an Account object with the value only for the Fields ["serialNumber", "account.accountName"].

Can anyone help on how to get List of Account[s] NOT List's of String with only two Fields after Distinct? Thanks

Comment: `distinct` is supposed to return the list of all values the specified field has in the collection.  Are you trying to do a `find` with a projection?  What output are you trying to get?

Comment: You can use an aggregate query with group stage to get distinct values and also other fields.